# How to extract coefficient of $x^n$ in an infinite product generating function?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Are there methods for obtaining the coefficient of
$x^n$ in a generating function like
$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty Q(x),$$
where $Q(x)$ is a rational function? This arises when we
want to count partitions of integers.

I have searched in Wilf's *generatingfunctionology*,
Goulden and Jackson's *Combinatorial Enumeration*,
Riordan's *Introduction to Combinatorics*, and
some books by George Andrews (his Number Theory book, and
his two books on integer partitions), but can't find
even an answer for very restricted cases.

Did I miss something, or is there really no known method
for that?

Comment: A first naïve guess would be that one must be lucky to find such a thing, since infinite products are rather nasty. However, I would also expect some nice bounds in some special cases and am interested to see those.

Comment: Did you really mean the factor in the product to be independent of $i$ (like taking an infinite power)? That would only makes sense if $Q(x)=1$. I suppose you meant $\prod_iQ_i(x)$

Answer (score 4):

Such an infinite product is only defined in the sense of formal power series if all factors have constant term$~1$ (one might allow a finite number of them to have a different constant term, but this never happens in practice), and if the next smallest power of $x$ in $Q_i(x)$ becomes ever larger as $i$ increases. Then to compute the coefficient of a specific power $x^n$, one only needs to consider finitely many factors in the product that contribute to it. This is actually the reason that such infinite products are defined as formal power series.